# Can I export TimeActivity with Payroll Items

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have web based time tracking application.  With the QuickBooks desktop edition I am able to export TimeActivity transactions that contain Customer Job, Service Item, and Payroll Item information assigned to the hours worked.

With the QuickBooks Online API it seems that I can't get PayrollItem Refs to attach to the TimeActivity transactions.  Is there a way to accomplish this with QuickBooks Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have support for Payroll Apis right now for QBO.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  Is there any sort of road map or future plans to implement this?  I can't seem to find any helpful information.

Comment: It is in plan but not pretty soon. Unfortunately, I do not have a date for you.